# Erosion Function in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, imagefilter, mathematical-morphology

I have to apply the method of erosion to an image.
However, I'm having some difficulties.
I'm starting with a basic example, but at this point all pixels of my image will stay with the value of the first pixel.
How to solve this problem?

```
public static int[] erosion(int array[])
{
    //int array1[] = new int[array.length];  
    // System.arraycopy(array, 0, array1, 0, array.length);          
    for(int i=1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i-1] < array[i]) {
            array[i] = array[i-1];
        }
        if (array[i+1] < array[i]) {
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        }
    }
    return array;       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the previous value in the array has been assigned at the next iteration pass. For in-place substitution you can try something like this:

```
int previous = array[0];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    int res = Math.min(previous, array[i]);
    res = Math.min(res, array[i + 1]);
    previous = array[i];
    array[i] = res;
}
array[array.length - 1] = Math.min(previous, array[array.length - 1];
```

Edit: extended to first and last values.

Comment: But, if i want array[i+2] and array[i+3], it's the same thing?

Comment: @FCoelho do you mean taking the minimum of a larger area of values? Then you need to keep more previous values (assuming you also want array[i - n] in the calculation), this keeps only one (corresponding to array[i - 1] in your question). At some point it becomes easier to just work on a copy, like in the answer by bas.

Comment: @FCoelho Another possibility is running the same loop more than once. That has the same effect of propagating the minimum values to a wider area.

Comment: i want 6 values in each iteration.

Comment: @FCoelho 6 does not fit neatly to calculating neighbours. If you mean 3 values on each side, then the easiest is to run that loop thrice. (and similarly for different widths; so there's a simple way to have configurable filter).